# How to extend laravel 4 core?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am a newb learning laravel 4. I want to override specific helper functions. Or add new functions to Url, Str etc. How to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Depending on what part of Laravel you want to extend or replace, there are different approaches.

#### Macros

Adding functions to Str is really easy, because of "macros":

Here's a short example for adding function:

```
Str::macro('test', function($str) {
    return 'Testing: ' . $str . '!';
});
```

You can then call this function as expected:

```
echo Str::test('text'); // Outputs "Testing: text!"
```

Adding functions using **macros are supported by Str, Form, HTML and Response**.

#### IOC Based Extension

To extend URL one must use the IOC of Laravel. This is explained in the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/extending#ioc-based-extension) (as mentioned by BenjaminRH). I agree it can be a bit hard to understand. Here's a step-by-step to extend URL:

1. Create folder *app/lib* to hold your extension classes.
2. Add this folder to autoloading:

   In *app/start/global.php*, append the lib path to the class loader:

   ```
   ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(
      app_path().'/commands',
      app_path().'/controllers',
      app_path().'/models',
      app_path().'/database/seeds',
      app_path().'/lib'
   ));
   ```

   Then add the path to *composer.json* classmap:

   ```
   "autoload": {
       "classmap": [
           "app/commands",
           "app/controllers",
           "app/models",
           "app/database/migrations",
           "app/database/seeds",
           "app/tests/TestCase.php",
           "app/lib"
       ]
   },
   ```
3. Create the custom UrlGenerator *app/lib/CustomUrlGenerator.php*:

   ```
   <?php 

   use \Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator;

   class CustomUrlGenerator extends UrlGenerator
   {
       public function test()
       {
           return $this->to('/test');
       }
   }
   ```
4. Create a service provider *app/lib/CustomRoutingServiceProvider.php*:

   ```
   <?php

   use \Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider;

   class CustomRoutingServiceProvider extends RoutingServiceProvider
   {
       public function boot()
       {
           App::bind('url', function()
           {
               return new CustomUrlGenerator(
                   App::make('router')->getRoutes(),
                   App::make('request')
               );
           });

           parent::boot();
       }
   }
   ```
5. Register the service provider in *app/config/app.php*:

   Add `CustomRoutingServiceProvider` to the *providers* array.
   For example, right after the Workbench provider:

   ```
   'Illuminate\Workbench\WorkbenchServiceProvider',
   'CustomRoutingServiceProvider',
   ```
6. Run `composer dump-autoload` from project root folder.
7. Done. Use like:

   ```
   URL::test();
   ```

**NOTE** *The code is tested, but may contain some errors*

Answer (score 1):

Interesting that you should mention this, actually. A [whole documentation section](http://four.laravel.com/docs/extending) was just recently added, which covers this in detail. It's very clear, and easy to understand. If you've been using Laravel at all, it might not even surprise you that Laravel actually provides an `extend` method for a lot of core components.

Comment: It all seems to confusing to me. I am still wrapping my head around IoC and ServiceProviders.

Comment: It can be very confusing if you haven't encountered it before :). Incidentally, you might want to check out the following library, which might have the methods you're looking for: http://anahkiasen.github.io/underscore-php/

Comment: Check out these [videos on IoC that Taylor put out](http://vimeo.com/userscape/videos/page:2/sort:date) before L4 was released - they are VERY useful for wrapping your head around the container, IoC and other goodies.

Answer (score 1):

Following Fnatte's answer, today's versions of Laravel do some extra processing in the `url` binding. Redefining the whole binding is no longer a practical option.

Here is how I ended up for extending the `URL` facade.

First, create your child class using this boilerplate:

```
use Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator;

class YourUrlGenerator extends UrlGenerator {

    public function __construct(UrlGenerator $url)
    {
        parent::__construct($url->routes, $url->request);
    }

    // redefine or add new methods here
}
```

Then, add this in a ServiceProvider:

```
$url = $this->app['url'];

$this->app->singleton('url', function() use ($url)
{
    return new YourUrlGenerator($url);
});
```

The point is simply that the original `url` binding should be executed at least once before we override it with our own.