# Overriding the login() method of Sentry 2 package in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, cartalyst-sentry

My basic aim is to extend the package class and override a method in it.

I have used Fnatte's ans as a reference : [How to extend laravel 4 core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123779/how-to-extend-laravel-4-core)

Sentry2 is a package that i am using for authentication in larval 4.

A user can be logged in using Sentry::login($credentials)

**I want to override the login method of the Sentry package and remove the check for activating the user(i have commented it in the code below)**

```
public function login(UserInterface $user, $remember = false)
    {
        #prevent throwing error if not activated !
        // if ( ! $user->isActivated())
        // {
        //  $login = $user->getLogin();
        //  throw new UserNotActivatedException("Cannot login user [$login] as they are not activated.");
        // }

        $this->user = $user;

        // Create an array of data to persist to the session and / or cookie
        $toPersist = array($user->getId(), $user->getPersistCode());

        // Set sessions
        $this->session->put($toPersist);

        if ($remember)
        {
            $this->cookie->forever($toPersist);
        }

        // The user model can attach any handlers
        // to the "recordLogin" event.
        $user->recordLogin();
    }
```

Steps i have done till now :

**1. Created a app/lib folder and added my extension class CustomSentry in it.**

**2. Added the app/lib folder to composer.json class map**

app/lib/CustomSentry.php :

```
    use Cartalyst\Sentry\Sentry;
      use Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserInterface;

        class CustomSentry extends Sentry{

        public function login(UserInterface $user, $remember = false){

             $this->user = $user;

            // Create an array of data to persist to the session and / or cookie
            $toPersist = array($user->getId(), $user->getPersistCode());

            // Set sessions
            $this->session->put($toPersist);

            if ($remember)
            {
                $this->cookie->forever($toPersist);
            }

            // The user model can attach any handlers
            // to the "recordLogin" event.
            $user->recordLogin();   



  }

}
```

**4. Created a service provider app/lib/CustomSentryServiceProvider**

```
 use Cartalyst\Sentry\SentryServiceProvider

    class CustomSentryServiceProvider extends SentryServiceProvider{

       //What should i put it here?
    }
```

**5. Register the service provider in app/config/app.php**

```
'CustomSentryServiceProvider'
```

**6. Use it as :**

```
Sentry::login($credentials);
```

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but a solution to the underlying problem. Instead of trying to remove the check from Sentry, why don't you activate each user as soon as they register? That's what I have done for my app - it's hosted on an intranet and accessible only to staff, so I didn't need the activation step. As soon as a user is created (by an administrator), it is activated in the controller.

Comment: Actually i want the user to activate his/her account so that i can prevent spamming. Its just that I want my signup procedure to be as short as possible followed by a instant login. Thus, i show the user an alert after log in that they their email is unverified. This will allow the user to use the app for a fixed time without verifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i figured out the answer to the question.

The better way to extend the class would be to use the same name. Since i am already using namespacing it would help reduce the confusion.

Assuming my apps name is MyApp i will only need to replace:

```
Cartalyst\Sentry
```

by:

```
MyApp\Cartalyst\Sentry
```

the rest of the SentryService provider can be copied as it is.

Then i can call the login method the normal way

```
Sentry::login($credentials)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have doubts, because you have to copy whole package/Sentry. Did you tried to extend the Sentry class? This this the best way to do what you want to achieve.